# What does "one every 4 and 97/100 seconds" mean?

Tags: javascript, time

I'm attempting to recreate a game AI system within JavaScript. Luckily, someone has made a post where they decompiled and listed the events - so i'm basing some of it from that.

They explained that the AI's activity level increases 1 every 4 and 97/100 seconds - what do they mean by this? Is a number randomly picked between 97 and 100, then the resulting number would be randomly picked between 4?

Lets say I had a variable called `activityLevel` set to `0`, and I wanted to increase the variable 1 every 4 and 97/100 seconds.

I have a random integer function here:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

How could I replicate "1 every 4 and 97/100 seconds" in JavaScript? Otherwise, what does it mean?

Comment: I think it just means every 4.97 seconds.

Comment: Just a guess but I'd read that as 4970 ms (i.e. just a bit less than 5 seconds)

Comment: `setInterval(..., 4970)`

Comment: https://javascript.info/number

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to decimal numbers, so the term "4 and 97/100" confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would interpret it as meaning every 4970 ms, which is 4.97 seconds.

That said, if you did want to vary between 97 and 100 (inclusive) hundredths of a second, you could do something like:

```
myVar = 4970 + getRandomInt(0, 31);
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why someone would go into the effort of saying "4 and 97/100" when they could just say "4.97"